# PHP Session not saving for redirect

Tags: php, session, adodb-php

I have a very basic php site using sessions for a login / password. I have a page doLogin.php that simply checks the username / password combo from post values and uses a JavaScript redirect to another page if the login is successful.

Sometimes for reasons I can't nail down, the login will be successful triggering the JavaScript redirect, but on the redirect the session values are gone. The connect function connects using ADODB database abstraction.

```
function doLogin()
{

if (array_key_exists('doLogin', $_POST))
    {
        $conn = connect(false);
        $pass = ms($_POST['password']);
        $email = ms($_POST['email']);

        $query = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$pass';";
        $r = $conn->execute($query);

        if ($r === false)
        {
            error_log('Error ' . $conn->errorNo() . " " . $conn->errorMsg());
            print "Unable to authenticate.";
        }

        if ($r->RecordCount())
        {
                $row = $r->FetchRow();
                $approval = $row['approval'];
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                if($approval == 1)
                {
                    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['security'] = $row['security'];
                    $_SESSION['f_name'] = $row['f_name'];
                    $_SESSION['l_name'] = $row['l_name'];
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                    $_SESSION['approval'] = $row['approval'];
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    session_write_close();
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.location="MYSITE/members"},1000)</script>';                                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = "";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $error = '<div class="warning" style="width: 920px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 25px 50px;">Invalid Username / Password combination.</div>
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location=\"MY SITE\"</script>';
        }
    }
return "$error";
}//end doLogin
```

I'm sure, I'm making an obvious mistake (besides the fact that I'm storing passwords as plain text). can anyone help me out?

EDIT:
The code for the page that does not store the sessions

```
<?php

  session_start();
  header("Cache-control: private"); //IE 6 Fix
  require_once '../php-inc/elements.php';
  require_once '../php-inc/database.php';
  $conn = connect(false);

//LOGOUT
    if (array_key_exists('logout', $_GET) && ($_GET['logout'] == 1) && !array_key_exists('doLogin', $_POST))
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION=array();
        $logout = '<br><br><div class="success" style="width: 920px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; padding:25px 50px;"><strong>You have successfully logged out.</strong></div><br><br>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.location="MYSITE.org"},3000)</script>';
    }


?>

<?php 

if(!empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{ 
    //SHOW STUFF
}

else
{
    $error = denyPermission();

    echo $error;    
}
?>
```

Comment: What the heck is the `ms()` function? "Make Safe"? Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Where's the page you're redirecting to?

Comment: ms() is lazy coding I haven't updated that really only includes returns $string = htmlspecialchars(utf8_decode($string));

Comment: the redirect page is another page on my site, i was trying to keep the login / session stuff on one page so i could figure out why it wasn't working, and then redirecting to the only page that requires login.

Comment: have you got multiple tabs open when the js redirects but session isn't created?

Comment: i'm sure that some of the users with the issue have multiple tabs open. could that cause sessions to not work? how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You must call `session_start()` on the pages that you are storing and retrieving values from the session.

[PHP session_start() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start)

Comment: i have session_start() at the top of every page, sorry I didn't include it here.

Comment: can you update the code and include the page that does not load the sessions?